# Undefined offset in 1 Error

Tags: php

i'm trying to exctract array with this code, but it gives that error. But if i remove while block from code and only give indice it works. Here is the code.

```
    //This function gives error: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in .......
//but if i delete while block and only write print $type[$i]; it works.

public function checkMimeType(){
        echo '<pre>';
        $i = 0;
        $type = array();
            foreach($this->_sourceFile as $key){

                $type= $key['type'];

            }
        while($i <= count($type))
        {
            print $type[$i].'<br>';
            $i++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming `$type = $key['type']` is a string? and you're trying to `count()` on a string followed by an array offset `$type[$1]` also on a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu're looping one time to often ;)

Index numbers start at zero. If there's one element in your array, the only index that is defined is therefore 0. `count()` will return 1. 
If you loop 'till `$i<= 1`, it will stop at `$i = 1`. There is no element with the ID of 1.

So, instead, use `while($i < count($type))`

Comment: thank you. it works now properly. by the way $i<= count($type)-1  is same right? thanks

Comment: @AskerMan Does the same thing, but isn't that clean. Why doing additional maths that isn't necessary?

Answer (score 0):

The count is not equal to the last index.

An array `[x, y, z]` has a count of `3`, but the last index is `2`.

So, in your while loop, you are not allowed to run until `<= count`, but only `< count`. When `$i`becomes `count` the index is out of bounds already.

Answer (score 0):

In your first loop you are not adding values to an array, you are overwriting the `$type` variable each time. Try this:

```
$type[] = $key['type'];
```

Edit: And also what @thst said

Comment: $type = $key['type'] doesnt overwrite. i check it now? are you sure?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. After the first loop is done, `$type` will contain only a single value, not an array of values. That's because you assign it a value each time, instead of adding the value to an array.

Comment: @Martin is completely right. You're not adding elements to your array, you're setting it to whatever is inside the last element inside $this->_sourceFile.

Comment: @MartinCernac Actually your last comment wasn't THAT right. While I'm sure you mean the right thing, it's not correct to assume it can never contain an array - after all you don't know what's inside _sourceFile ;)

Comment: @JohannesH. You're right, I chose my words poorly .. I need to get some sleep :-)